# ComboBox options receive margin upon making the stage resizable

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

I've got a `ComboBox` within a JavaFX `Stage` through FXML. Normally this works as expected. However, once I make the stage unresizable through `stage.setResizable(false);`, the options of the `ComboBox` receive a slight margin as seen below:

[image]

The `ComboBox` has no custom styles and even when using a `Stage` containing *only* the `ComboBox`, the resizable option causes this effect. Is there any way to prevent this from happening and keeping the options aligned with the `ComboBox` at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your code on Java 8 (latest current release version) and seeing if the issue is fixed for you.

See related question:
  [JavaFX: Why does stage.setResizable(false) cause additional margins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732100/javafx-why-does-stage-setresizablefalse-cause-additional-margin)

And bug report:
  [RT-36413: Initial stage size set incorrectly for non-resizable stages](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36413).

I don't know of a clean workaround for your case.

Your bug likely has the same route cause as RT-36413, but exhibits somewhat behaviour, I suggest filing another bug report at https://javafx-jira.kenai.com (make sure you mention the existing RT-36413 bug in your new bug report).

Comment: Thanks! Updating to JRE8 has resolved the issue. The `sizeToScene` from the other question's answer wasn't needed for me.