# Why is my JavaFX window not the right width?

Tags: java, windows, javafx

When I make a JavaFX window:

```
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 800);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

The resulting window is about 610 pixels wide.

If I use setWidth:

```
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 800);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setWidth(600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

The window ends up being about 594 pixels wide.

Why does this happen, and how can I get my window to be the correct size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's [a long standing bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732100/javafx-why-does-stage-setresizablefalse-cause-additional-margins) that happens when setResizable is used.

I fixed it by using the sizeToScene function.

```
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 800);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Well, there is this bug, but also you assume, that scene width = stage width, which isn't necessarily true, since the stage size includes decorations...