# Unresizable ever JavaFX Window

Tags: java, javafx

My problem is that my JavaFX window expands further than it should at the bottom, thus showing a weird blank background...

I set `stage.setResizable(false)` but it doesn't seem to work. I also set

```
stage.setMinWidth(1280);
stage.setMaxWidth(1280);
stage.setMinHeight(800);
stage.setMaxHeight(800);
```

I think it's due to some `ImageView` bigger than the window, but I really would like my window to stick to the max I set and be absolutely not resizable ever.

Here's what it looks like : [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKKAZ.png)

I also noticed it happens only when I set `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT)`.
But I don't want my window to be decorated with `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED)`... :(

Thank you in advance for your help. :)

Comment: What makes you sure the height it is is not 800?

Comment: Because when I don't put this node which overflow the window, it works well. And because I know what 1280*800 looks like.

Comment: Fair enough. I upvoted, hopefully this gets some more attention. Check this out and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732100/javafx-why-does-stage-setresizablefalse-cause-additional-margins

Comment: I tried it out, and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried directly using `setWidth` and `setHeight`:

```
stage.setWidth(1280);
stage.setHeight(800);
```

I think the setMaxWidth, setMinHeight... etc. only works on a decorated screen because its main purpose is to limit the sizes the user can set the window. Here's my example:

```
public class FixedWindowSize extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Pane p = new Pane();
        p.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, null, null)));
        p.setMinSize(6000, 6000); //Make this go out beyond window bounds.
        Scene s = new Scene(p);

        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

        //This doesn't work
        //primaryStage.setMinWidth(1280);
        //primaryStage.setMaxWidth(1280);
        //primaryStage.setMinHeight(800);
        //primaryStage.setMaxHeight(800);

        //This should work.
        primaryStage.setWidth(1280);
        primaryStage.setHeight(800);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: I feel stupid I didn't think of that... It really makes sense now. Thank you very much for your answer! :)