# Why is jre-8 adding extra space on the right and bottom of my JavaFX application?

Tags: java, java-8, javafx-8

I was writing a game using JavaFX. When I compiled the code using **jdk-9**, everything worked fine but when I compiled it using **jdk-8u102** and ran the program, there was some extra space(about *10 pixels*) on the right and bottom of the application window. In both cases the *Scene* size was correct but in case of java 8, the *Stage* is bigger on the right and bottom(although inquiring about the width or height of the Stage, using *Stage.getWidth()* or *Stage.getHeight()* methods, returns the same values in both cases).

I tried updating to **jdk-8u151** but that didn't solve the problem.

**Note -** When I compiled the program using jdk-8 but ran using jre-9, the problem wasn't there anymore. So I'm guessing, the problem can be with the run time environment of java 8 instead of the jdk itself.

I found that **Stage.setResizable(false)** is causing the problem in jre-8. Also, I'm using Windows and the problem doesn't seem to be with jre-8 on linux.

Here is a code snippet of the application:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ImageView spaceBackground = new ImageView("space.jpg");
    spaceBackground.setFitHeight(600);
    spaceBackground.setFitWidth(900);

    Group group = new Group(spaceBackground);
    Scene scene = new Scene(group, 900, 600);  

    primaryStage.setResizable(false);    // this method is causing the problem
    /*
    rest of the code
    */
}
```

This is a screen capture of the application window, running under **jre-9**:
[image]

And here is the one running under **jre-8**:
[image: notice the white spaces on the right and bottom]

Can anyone tell me what the cause might be here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Are you shure you don't resize the scene somewhere?

Comment: @mayamar No, I'm not resizing the scene anywhere. Besides I'm taking the same source code and compiling and running it under _jre-8_ and _jre-9_. Also, just running the code snippet I provided, wont reproduce the problem.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help **must** include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself. Please read how to create a [MCVE].

Comment: Any chance the following question contains related hints? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732100/javafx-why-does-stage-setresizablefalse-cause-additional-margins

Comment: @mayamar I've updated the code snippet and it will now reproduce the problem I'm having.

Comment: Yes @Hay _Stage.sizeToScene()_ solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: I suspect `new Scene(group)` (without setting an explicit size) also would solve the problem.