# Snake AI that uses MLP and GA to learn doesn't exhibit intelligent behavior even after thousands of generations

Tags: java, machine-learning, javafx, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I'm a high school senior who's working on a project for my CS research class (I'm very lucky to have the opportunity to be in such a class)! The project is to make an AI learn the popular game, Snake, with a Multilayer Perceptron (MLP) that learns through Genetic Algorithm (GA). This project is heavily inspired by many videos I've seen on Youtube accomplishing what I've just described, as you can see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhiO4WsHA6c) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bhP7zulFfY&). I've written the project described above using JavaFX and an AI library called [Neuroph](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/).

This is what my program looks like currently:
[image: GeneticSnake Project]

The name is irrelevant, as I have a list of nouns and adjectives I used to generate them from (I thought it would make it more interesting). The number in the parenthesis for Score is the best score in that generation, since only 1 snake is shown at a time.

When breeding, I set x% of the snakes to be parents (in this case, 20). The number of children is then divided up evenly for each pair of snake parents. The "genes" in this case, are the weights of the MLP. Since my library doesn't really support biases, I added a bias neuron to the input layer and connected it to all of the other neurons in every layer for its weights to act as biases instead (as described in a thread [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/neuroph/discussion/862858/thread/0aa01466/)). Each of the snake's children has a 50, 50 chance of getting either parents' gene for every gene. There is also a 5% chance for a gene to mutate, where it's set to a random number between -1.0 and 1.0.

Each snake's MLP has 3 layers: 18 input neurons, 14 hidden ones, and 4 output neurons (for each direction). The inputs I feed it are the x of head, y of head, x of food, y of food, and steps left. It also looks in 4 directions, and check for the distance to food, wall, and itself (if it doesn't see it, it's set to -1.0). There's also the bias neuron I talked about which brings the number to 18 after adding it.

The way I calculate a snake's score is through my fitness function, which is (apples consumed × 5 + seconds alive / 2)

Here is my GAMLPAgent.java, where all the MLP and GA stuff happens.

```
package agents;

import graphics.Snake;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import org.neuroph.core.Layer;
import org.neuroph.nnet.MultiLayerPerceptron;
import org.neuroph.nnet.comp.neuron.BiasNeuron;
import org.neuroph.util.NeuralNetworkType;
import org.neuroph.util.TransferFunctionType;
import util.Direction;

/**
 *
 * @author Preston Tang
 *
 * GAMLPAgent stands for Genetic Algorithm Multi-Layer Perceptron Agent
 */
public class GAMLPAgent implements Comparable<GAMLPAgent> {

    public Snake mask;

    private final MultiLayerPerceptron mlp;

    private final int width;
    private final int height;
    private final double size;

    private final double mutationRate = 0.05;

    public GAMLPAgent(Snake mask, int width, int height, double size) {
        this.mask = mask;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.size = size;

        //Input: x of head, y of head, x of food, y of food, steps left
        //Input: 4 directions, check for distance to food, wall, and self  + 1 bias neuron (18 total)
        //6 hidden perceptrons (2 hidden layer(s))
        //Output: A direction, 4 possibilities
        mlp = new MultiLayerPerceptron(TransferFunctionType.SIGMOID, 18, 14, 4);
        //Adding connections
        List<Layer> layers = mlp.getLayers();

        for (int r = 0; r < layers.size(); r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < layers.get(r).getNeuronsCount(); c++) {
                mlp.getInputNeurons().get(mlp.getInputsCount() - 1).addInputConnection(layers.get(r).getNeuronAt(c));
            }
        }

//        System.out.println(mlp.getInputNeurons().get(17).getInputConnections() + " " + mlp.getInputNeurons().get(17).getOutConnections());
        mlp.randomizeWeights();

//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mlp.getInputNeurons().get(17).getWeights()));
    }

    public void compute() {
        if (mask.isAlive()) {
            Rectangle head = mask.getSnakeParts().get(0);
            Rectangle food = mask.getFood();

            double headX = head.getX();
            double headY = head.getY();
            double foodX = mask.getFood().getX();
            double foodY = mask.getFood().getY();
            int stepsLeft = mask.getSteps();

            double foodL = -1.0, wallL, selfL = -1.0;
            double foodR = -1.0, wallR, selfR = -1.0;
            double foodU = -1.0, wallU, selfU = -1.0;
            double foodD = -1.0, wallD, selfD = -1.0;

            //The 4 directions
            //Left Direction
            if (head.getY() == food.getY() && head.getX() > food.getX()) {
                foodL = head.getX() - food.getX();
            }

            wallL = head.getX() - size;

            for (Rectangle part : mask.getSnakeParts()) {
                if (head.getY() == part.getY() && head.getX() > part.getX()) {
                    selfL = head.getX() - part.getX();
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Right Direction
            if (head.getY() == food.getY() && head.getX() < food.getX()) {
                foodR = food.getX() - head.getX();
            }

            wallR = size * width - head.getX();

            for (Rectangle part : mask.getSnakeParts()) {
                if (head.getY() == part.getY() && head.getX() < part.getX()) {
                    selfR = part.getX() - head.getX();
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Up Direction
            if (head.getX() == food.getX() && head.getY() < food.getY()) {
                foodU = food.getY() - head.getY();
            }

            wallU = size * height - head.getY();

            for (Rectangle part : mask.getSnakeParts()) {
                if (head.getX() == part.getX() && head.getY() < part.getY()) {
                    selfU = part.getY() - head.getY();
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Down Direction
            if (head.getX() == food.getX() && head.getY() > food.getY()) {
                foodD = head.getY() - food.getY();
            }

            wallD = head.getY() - size;

            for (Rectangle part : mask.getSnakeParts()) {
                if (head.getX() == part.getX() && head.getY() > part.getY()) {
                    selfD = head.getY() - food.getY();
                    break;
                }
            }

            mlp.setInput(
                    headX, headY, foodX, foodY, stepsLeft,
                    foodL, wallL, selfL,
                    foodR, wallR, selfR,
                    foodU, wallU, selfU,
                    foodD, wallD, selfD, 1);

            mlp.calculate();

            if (getIndexOfLargest(mlp.getOutput()) == 0) {
                mask.setDirection(Direction.UP);
            } else if (getIndexOfLargest(mlp.getOutput()) == 1) {
                mask.setDirection(Direction.DOWN);
            } else if (getIndexOfLargest(mlp.getOutput()) == 2) {
                mask.setDirection(Direction.LEFT);
            } else if (getIndexOfLargest(mlp.getOutput()) == 3) {
                mask.setDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
            }
        }
    }

    public double[][] breed(GAMLPAgent agent, int num) {
        //Converts Double[] to double[]
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109988/how-do-i-convert-double-to-double
        double[] parent1 = Stream.of(mlp.getWeights()).mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
        double[] parent2 = Stream.of(agent.getMLP().getWeights()).mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();

        double[][] childGenes = new double[num][parent1.length];

        for (int r = 0; r < num; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < childGenes[r].length; c++) {
                if (new Random().nextInt(100) <= mutationRate * 100) {
                    childGenes[r][c] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-1.0, 1.0);
//childGenes[r][c] += childGenes[r][c] * 0.1;
                } else {
                    childGenes[r][c] = new Random().nextDouble() < 0.5 ? parent1[c] : parent2[c];
                }
            }
        }

        return childGenes;
    }

    public MultiLayerPerceptron getMLP() {
        return mlp;
    }

    public void setMask(Snake mask) {
        this.mask = mask;
    }

    public Snake getMask() {
        return mask;
    }

    public int getIndexOfLargest(double[] array) {
        if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
            return -1; // null or empty
        }
        int largest = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[largest]) {
                largest = i;
            }
        }
        return largest; // position of the first largest found
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(GAMLPAgent t) {
        if (this.getMask().getScore() < t.getMask().getScore()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (t.getMask().getScore() < this.getMask().getScore()) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void debugLocation() {
        Rectangle head = mask.getSnakeParts().get(0);
        Rectangle food = mask.getFood();
        System.out.println(head.getX() + " " + head.getY() + " " + food.getX() + " " + food.getY());
        System.out.println(mask.getName() + ": " + Arrays.toString(mlp.getOutput()));
    }

    public void debugInput() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < mlp.getInputNeurons().size(); i++) {
            s += mlp.getInputNeurons().get(i).getOutput() + " ";
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public double[] getOutput() {
        return mlp.getOutput();
    }
}
```

This is the main class of my code, GeneticSnake2.java, where the game loop is located, and where I assign genes to the child snakes (I know that it could be done more cleanly).

```
package main;

import agents.GAMLPAgent;
import ui.InfoBar;
import graphics.Snake;
import graphics.SnakeGrid;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Preston Tang
 */
public class GeneticSnake2 extends Application {

    private final int width = 45;
    private final int height = 40;

    private final double displaySize = 120;
    private final double size = 12;

    private final Color pathColor = Color.rgb(120, 120, 120);
    private final Color wallColor = Color.rgb(50, 50, 50);

    private final int initSnakeLength = 2;

    private final int populationSize = 1000;

    private int generation = 0;

    private int initSteps = 100;
    private int stepsIncrease = 50;

    private double parentPercentage = 0.2;

    private final ArrayList<Color> snakeColors = new ArrayList() {
        {
            add(Color.GREEN);
            add(Color.RED);
            add(Color.YELLOW);
            add(Color.BLUE);
            add(Color.MAGENTA);
            add(Color.PINK);
            add(Color.ORANGERED);
            add(Color.BLACK);
            add(Color.GOLDENROD);
            add(Color.WHITE);
        }
    };

    private final ArrayList<Snake> snakes = new ArrayList<>();

    private final ArrayList<GAMLPAgent> agents = new ArrayList<>();

    private long initTime = System.nanoTime();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Pane graphics = new Pane();
        graphics.setPrefHeight(height * size);
        graphics.setPrefWidth(width * size);
        graphics.setTranslateX(0);
        graphics.setTranslateY(displaySize);

        Pane display = new Pane();
        display.setStyle("-fx-background-color: BLACK");
        display.setPrefHeight(displaySize);
        display.setPrefWidth(width * size);
        display.setTranslateX(0);
        display.setTranslateY(0);

        root.getChildren().add(display);

        SnakeGrid sg = new SnakeGrid(pathColor, wallColor, width, height, size);

        //Parsing "adjectives.txt" and "nouns.txt" to form possible names
        ArrayList<String> adjectives = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(readFile(new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/adjectives.txt").getFile())).split("\n")));
        ArrayList<String> nouns = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(readFile(new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/nouns.txt").getFile())).split("\n")));

        //Initializing the population
        for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++) {
            //Get random String from lists and capitalize first letter
            String adj = adjectives.get(new Random().nextInt(adjectives.size()));
            adj = adj.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + adj.substring(1);

            String noun = nouns.get(new Random().nextInt(nouns.size()));
            noun = noun.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + noun.substring(1);

            Color color = snakeColors.get(new Random().nextInt(snakeColors.size()));

            //We want to see the first snake
            if (i == 0) {
                InfoBar bar = new InfoBar();
                bar.getStatusText().setText("Status: Alive");
                bar.getStatusText().setFill(Color.GREENYELLOW);
                bar.getSizeText().setText("Population Size: " + populationSize);

                Snake snake = new Snake(bar, adj + " " + noun, width, height, size, initSnakeLength, color, initSteps, stepsIncrease);
                bar.getNameText().setText("Name: " + snake.getName());

                snakes.add(snake);
                agents.add(new GAMLPAgent(snake, width, height, size));

            } else {
                Snake snake = new Snake(adj + " " + noun, width, height, size, initSnakeLength, color, initSteps, stepsIncrease);

                snakes.add(snake);
                agents.add(new GAMLPAgent(snake, width, height, size));
            }
        }

        //Focused on original snake
        display.getChildren().add(snakes.get(0).getInfoBar());

        graphics.getChildren().addAll(sg);

        graphics.getChildren().addAll(snakes.get(0));

        root.getChildren().add(graphics);

        //Add the speed controller (slider)
        Slider slider = new Slider(1, 10, 10);
        slider.setTranslateX(205);
        slider.setTranslateY(75);
        slider.setDisable(true);

        root.getChildren().add(slider);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, width * size, height * size + displaySize);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        //Fixes the setResizable bug
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732100/javafx-why-does-stage-setresizablefalse-cause-additional-margins
        stage.setTitle("21-GeneticSnake2 Cause the First Version Got Deleted ;-; Started on 6/8/2020");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            private long lastUpdate = 0;

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                if (now - lastUpdate >= (10 - (int) slider.getValue()) * 50_000_000) {
                    lastUpdate = now;

                    int alive = populationSize;
                    for (int i = 0; i < snakes.size(); i++) {
                        Snake snake = snakes.get(i); //Current snake

                        if (i == 0) {
                            Collections.sort(agents);
                            snake.getInfoBar().getScoreText().setText("Score: " + snake.getScore() + " (" + agents.get(agents.size() - 1).getMask().getScore() + ")");
                        }

                        if (!snake.isAlive()) {
                            alive--;

                            //Update graphics for main snake
                            if (i == 0) {
                                snake.getInfoBar().getStatusText().setText("Status: Dead");
                                snake.getInfoBar().getStatusText().setFill(Color.RED);
                                graphics.getChildren().remove(snake);
                            }

                        } else {
                            //If out of steps
                            if (snake.getSteps() <= 0) {
                                snake.setAlive(false);
                            }

                            //Bounds Detection (left right up down)
                            if (snake.getSnakeParts().get(0).getX() >= width * size
                                    || snake.getSnakeParts().get(0).getX() <= 0
                                    || snake.getSnakeParts().get(0).getY() >= height * size
                                    || snake.getSnakeParts().get(0).getY() <= 0) {
                                snake.setAlive(false);
                            }

                            //Self-Collision Detection
                            for (int o = 1; o < snakes.get(o).getSnakeParts().size(); o++) {
                                if (snakes.get(o).getSnakeParts().get(0).getX() == snakes.get(o).getSnakeParts().get(o).getX()
                                        && snakes.get(o).getSnakeParts().get(0).getY() == snakes.get(o).getSnakeParts().get(o).getY()) {
                                    snakes.get(o).setAlive(false);
                                }
                            }

                            int rate = (int) slider.getValue();
                            int seconds = (int) ((System.nanoTime() - initTime) * rate / 1_000_000_000);

                            agents.get(i).compute();
                            snake.manageMovement();
                            snake.setSecondsAlive(seconds);

//                            agents.get(0);
//                            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(agents.get(0).getOutput()));
//                            
//                            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                            //Expression to calculate score
                            double exp = (snake.getConsumed() * 5 + snake.getSecondsAlive() / 2.0D);
//double exp = snake.getSteps() + (Math.pow(2, snake.getConsumed()) + Math.pow(snake.getConsumed(), 2.1) * 500)
//        - (Math.pow(snake.getConsumed(), 1.2) * Math.pow(0.25 * snake.getSteps(), 1.3));

                            snake.setScore(Math.round(exp * 100.0) / 100.0);

                            //Update graphics for main snake
                            if (i == 0) {
                                snake.getInfoBar().getTimeText().setText("Time Survived: " + snake.getSecondsAlive() + "s");
                                snake.getInfoBar().getFoodText().setText("Food Consumed: " + snake.getConsumed());
                                snake.getInfoBar().getGenerationText().setText("Generation: " + generation);
                                snake.getInfoBar().getStepsText().setText("Steps Remaining: " + snake.getSteps());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Reset and breed
                    if (alive == 0) {
                        //Ascending order
                        initTime = System.nanoTime();
                        generation++;
                        graphics.getChildren().clear();
                        graphics.getChildren().addAll(sg);
                        snakes.clear();

                        //x% of snakes are parents
                        int parentNum = (int) (populationSize * parentPercentage);

                        //Faster odd number check
                        if ((parentNum & 1) != 0) {
                            //If odd make even
                            parentNum += 1;
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < parentNum; i += 2) {
                            //Get the 2 parents, sorted by score
                            GAMLPAgent p1 = agents.get(populationSize - (i + 2));
                            GAMLPAgent p2 = agents.get(populationSize - (i + 1));

                            //Produce the next generation
                            double[][] childGenes = p1.breed(p2, ((populationSize - parentNum) / parentNum) * 2);

                            //Debugs Genes
//                            System.out.println(Arrays
//                                    .stream(childGenes)
//                                    .map(Arrays::toString)
//                                    .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
                            //Soft copy
                            ArrayList<GAMLPAgent> temp = new ArrayList<>(agents);

                            for (int o = 0; o < childGenes.length; o++) {
                                temp.get(o).getMLP().setWeights(childGenes[o]);
                            }

                            //Add the genes of every pair of parents to the children
                            for (int o = 0; o < childGenes.length; o++) {
                                //Useful debug message
//                                System.out.println("ParentNum: " + parentNum
//                                        + " ChildPerParent: " + (populationSize - parentNum) / parentNum
//                                        + " Index: " + (o + (i / 2 * childGenes.length))
//                                        + " ChildGenesNum: " + childGenes.length
//                                        + " Var O: " + o);

                                //Adds the genes of the temp to the agents
                                agents.set((o + (i / 2 * childGenes.length)), temp.get(o));
                            }
//                            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                        }

                        //Debugging the snakes' genes to a file
//                        String str = "";
//                        for (int i = 0; i < agents.size(); i++) {
//                            str += "Index: " + i + "\t" + Arrays.toString(agents.get(i).getMLP().getWeights())+  "\n\n\n";
//                        }
//
//                        printToFile(str, "gen" + generation);

                        for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++) {
                            //Get random String from lists and capitalize first letter
                            String adj = adjectives.get(new Random().nextInt(adjectives.size()));
                            adj = adj.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + adj.substring(1);

                            String noun = nouns.get(new Random().nextInt(nouns.size()));
                            noun = noun.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + noun.substring(1);

                            Color color = snakeColors.get(new Random().nextInt(snakeColors.size()));

                            //We want to see the first snake
                            if (i == 0) {
                                InfoBar bar = new InfoBar();
                                bar.getStatusText().setText("Status: Alive");
                                bar.getStatusText().setFill(Color.GREENYELLOW);
                                bar.getSizeText().setText("Population Size: " + populationSize);

                                Snake snake = new Snake(bar, adj + " " + noun, width, height, size, initSnakeLength, color, initSteps, stepsIncrease);
                                bar.getNameText().setText("Name: " + snake.getName());
                                snakes.add(snake);
                                agents.get(i).setMask(snake);
                            } else {
                                Snake snake = new Snake(adj + " " + noun, width, height, size, initSnakeLength, color, initSteps, stepsIncrease);
                                snakes.add(snake);
                                agents.get(i).setMask(snake);
                            }
                        }

                        graphics.getChildren().add(snakes.get(0));
                        display.getChildren().clear();

                        //Focused on original snake at first
                        display.getChildren().add(snakes.get(0).getInfoBar());
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        //Starts the infinite loop
        timer.start();
    }

    public String readFile(File f) {
        String content = "";
        try {
            content = new Scanner(f).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error: Unable to read " + f.getName());
        }
        return content;
    }

    public void printToFile(String str, String name) {
        FileWriter fileWriter;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(name + ".txt");
            try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)) {
                bufferedWriter.write(str);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The main problem is that even after a few thousand generations, the snakes are still simply suiciding into the wall. In the videos I linked above, the snakes were avoiding walls and getting food at like generation 5. I suspect the problem is located in the main class where I'm assigning genes to the snakes that have been born.

I've actually been stuck on this for a few weeks. Before, one of the problems I suspected was a lack of inputs, since I had way less back then. But now, I think that it is no longer the case. If needed, I can try to look in the 4 diagonal directions to add another 12 inputs to the snake's MLP. I've also went to the Artificial Intelligence Discord to ask for help, but a solution hasn't really been found.

If needed, I'm willing to send my entire code so you could run the simulation for yourself.

If you've read up to here, thank you for taking time out of your day to help me! I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please comment if you feel that my question needs some edits to improve it/add more information. I've already made my question pretty detailed, but if it's not enough, I'm happy to add more!

Comment: Java developers with AI experience are few.  You've asked a good question that might not get answered.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that! I appreciate it :)

Comment: from @GilbertLeBlanc s comment it looks like this is unrelated to fx (just accidentally showing in the ui)? If so, in your shoes I would  try to make the logic (AI) work as needed without ui before moving on to implement it with fx. All that said: it's too broad for this site, IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The question is pretty broad—I went to other sources before posting my answer here on StackOverflow, so this is kind of a last resort to me.

Comment: It looks like you need to include factors more in determining the "best" snakes to breed, maybe make target seeking more rewarding rather than just staying alive. Take a look at the code from Code Bullet here showing some of what he did, although it's not the project from the vid: https://github.com/Code-Bullet/SnakeFusion Specifically check the `calcFitness()` method of the snake https://github.com/Code-Bullet/SnakeFusion/blob/master/SmartSnakesCombine/Snake.pde

Comment: Just wanted to check, but are you doing indiscriminate breeding rather than selective breeding of the "best" snakes after each generation? You mention in your code comments that the `agents` list is sorted by score, but I cant see any code that sorts the list, and that may explain why you have little progress after so many generations?

Comment: That "self collision detection" code seems weird. Pretty much seems like you refer to different snakes there. Also why do you create new `Random` instances basically every time you need a random value? If possible you should restrict yourself to one instance. Moreover this code combines the AI logic and the gui in an (imho) unhealthy way: The animation should be seperate from the AI evaluation; doing evaluation and animation at the same time you simply make the logic more complex than needed while at the same time restricting both animation and AI evaluation.

Comment: @sorifiend Thanks for the comment! In the game loop on top, I'm actually constantly sorting the list in order to get the current best score (the one that's within the brackets). But to be safe, I added a `Collections.sort` right before the breeding code. I also used CodeBullet's fitness function instead of mine. Sadly (after running it for 500 generations), the snakes still don't seem to be improving--in fact, the score seems to be stuck between 32 to 1500, and they don't eat more than 2 or 3 food (which I assume is kind of based on luck).

Comment: @fabian Thanks for the suggestions! As a highschooler, I still have many, many things I can improve on in terms of wasting memory (the multiple `Random` instances). For the self collision detection code, I'm actually just comparing the head of the snake to its snake parts, as the for loop starts at 1, and in the loop I reference the snake head (its index is 0). For the animation and AI logic--I do agree that the UI complicates things a lot. The class that I took last year was all about algorithms and super basic AI, but every project required graphics, which is why I have this habit.

Comment: I'd still expect **self** collision to compare with different snakes instead of different ones; the loop could also result in a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, if there are more snake parts than snakes (Replace `snakes.get(o)` with `snake` here: `for(int o = 1; o < snakes.get(o).getSnakeParts().size(); o++) { if(snakes.get(o).getSnakeParts().get(0).getX() == snakes.get(o).getSnakeParts().get(o).getX()
                                        && snakes.get(o).getSnakeParts().get(0).getY() == snakes.get(o).getSnakeParts().get(o).getY()) { snakes.get(o).setAlive(false); } }`)

Comment: @fabian Each snake is basically in a separate instance, it can't interact with the other snakes. If I remember correctly, `snakes.get(o)` and `snake` reference the exact same thing, but making the change would make my code more readable. I was originally kinda lazy so I just used `snakes.get(o)` for everything. I then added the `snake` variable, but I forgot to change a few, which is why the ones you stated on top haven't been changed. Thanks for the comment though! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not surprised your snakes are dying.

Let's take a step back. What is AI exactly? Well, it's a search problem. We're searching through some parameter space to find the set of parameters that solve snake given the current state of the game. You can imagine a space of parameters that has a global minimum: the best possible snake, the snake that makes the fewest mistakes.

All learning algorithms start at some point in this parameters space and attempt to find that global maximum over time. First, let's think about MLPs. MLPs learn by trying a set of weights, computing a loss function, and then taking a step in the direction that would further minimize the loss (gradient descent). It's fairly obvious that an MLP will find a minimum, but whether it can find a good enough minimum is a question and there are a lot of training techniques that exist to improve that chance.

Genetic algorithms, on the other hand, have very poor convergence characteristics. First, let's stop calling these genetic algorithms. Let's call these
smorgasbord algorithms instead. A smorgasbord algorithm takes two sets of parameters from two parents, jumbles them, and then yields a new smorgasbord. What makes you think this would be a better smorgasbord than either of the two? What are you minimizing here? How do you know it's approaching anything better? If you attach a loss function, how do you know you're in a space that can actually be minimized?

The point I'm trying to make is that genetic algorithms are unprincipled, unlike nature. Nature does not just put codons in a blender to make a new strand of DNA, but that's exactly what genetic algorithms do. There are techniques to add some time of hill climbing, but still genetic algorithms have [tons of problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm#Limitations).

Point is, don't get swept up in the name. Genetic algorithms are simply smorgasbord algorithms. My view is that your approach doesn't work because GAs have no guarantees of converging after *infinite* iterations and MLPs have no guarantees of converging to a good global minimum.

What to do? Well, a better approach would be to use a learning paradigm that fits your problem. That better approach would be to use reinforcement learning. There's a very good [course on Udacity from Georgia Tech](https://www.udacity.com/course/reinforcement-learning--ud600) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer explaining the flaws of my approach, as well as linking a course on the topic of reinforcement learning! I really liked how you broke down the topic of Genetic Algorithms, and it was very informational.